# How to interpret "Get it over with"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I do really enjoy how rich the language of adpositions is, but *two* of those in a row is something rare to me.

So I just heard this phrase in an HBO show:

> — […]
>
> — Get it over with.

It appeared in a context of stopping a frustrated person from talking about their problem anymore. To me, it sounds a lot like *Deal with it*. Am I close?.. I have a somewhat uneasy understanding over the *with*.

Is this any valid grammar at all?

Comment: It means just do it so that it will be finished as quickly as possible.

Comment: It can be used in several senses, depending on context (and you give us none).  (And note that one might confuse that idiom and "get over it", which has a different meaning.)

Comment: We may need more context, perhaps more parts of the dialogue, but I do believe the comments here are accurate.

Comment: There is also an idiom "get over it" - which means "stop dwelling on it" or "stop thinking about a past event".  Are you sure you transcribed what you heard correctly?

Comment: *Get it over with* often means *Go ahead and do/complete it*. Another colloquial way to say it is *Just do it already*.

Comment: @Clare - I think you should put this in an answer.  It sounds right to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Oxford English Dictionary* defines **to get it over with** as

> to complete an unpleasant or tedious but necessary task promptly.

The [Oxford dictionary online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/get_something_over_with)  (ODO) defines *get something over with* as

> Do or undergo something unpleasant or difficult, so as to be rid of it.

So yes, one could say this to someone who is [bent on](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bent)  talking and talking about some unpleasant chore and not really wanting to do it.

Examples from the OED:

> The thing had to be done, and the sooner he got it over with the better.

(1899   Vassar Misc. (Vassar Coll., N.Y.) Feb. 211)

> I sense that he is dog-tired and just wants to get the meeting over with.

(2004   S. Mehta Maximum City 332)

From the ODO:

> ‘I suppose it was a good idea to get it over with quickly.’

Once a task is finished, you can say the task  is

**over and done with** or **over with**

> It will be hard work to get through the three months to Cousin Maria's wedding; I wish it were ‘over and done with’.

(1822   M. Arden Diary in National Mag. (1856) Nov. 54/1)

> I was shaking and sweating at the checkout, wanting it to be over with, wanting to be out of there.

(1999   T. Parsons Man & Boy (2000) xii. 101)

See also the [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/over_and_done_with)